# I have a very low amount of employer views, is this common?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Right now I have a profile completeness of 171/210, I indicated interest in a full-time position, contract and internship and I am willing to relocate to the US, UK, Netherlands, Germany, Ireland, Australia and Canada.
Combined with around 20 top-tags I thought it should make for a decent profile.

So far, after about 1 year of having this profile, I have received 898 public views, 23 search hits and only 2 employer views. This number is much lower than I would credit my profile so I'm left to wonder what it is exactly that's causing this (I'm assuming the public views exist mainly because I link to it on my profile).

Is there any data available to see what employers are looking for and how location/work status (I'm a student)/experience/certain tags/etc affect your chances of popping up at search?

Comment: I'd say that's normal. With linking my profile from various locations, even after a good 2+ years I still only have 38 employer views.

Comment: How can you see at what date you signed up for Careers? I currently have 20 employer views, but I can't say how that compares to you guys. Also, it's strange that there's no meta.careers site.

Comment: I don't think you can view the exact date somewhere, I just looked at the oldest mail I received from Careers 2.0 and made an educated guess.

Comment: On the other hand, I had had "Public views 6, Employer views 23". That's probably because I never posted my Career link in my personal sites, but did sent a number of applications from Careers. My hypothesis is that Public view would probably be correlated with you posting your profile link to personal sites, while Employer view would probably be correlated with sending applications through Careers.

Comment: It's weekend, even the Careers team is probably at home taking some rest. Give them some time, usually they're the fastest to respond.

Comment: We're looking into this to make sure there is no bug before providing a more in depth answer.  As to the last question, there currently is no information that we provide candidates on what is being searched.  Sounds like a good blog post idea!